Terraform: Use count.index in variable name
Is it possible to use count.index in a variable name, so I can use a single map variable for multiple resources? For example
variables.tf:
variable "disk_share_sizes" {
  type        = map(number)
  description = "Sizes for VM Disks and File Shares"
  default = {
    fileshare   = 2048
    pvs0        = 20
    pvs1        = 10
    cca0        = 50
    cca1        = 80
  }
}

compute.tf
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "vm_pvs" {
  count                = 2
  name                 = "pvs-disk-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  location             = "useast"
  resource_group_name  = "MyRGName"
  storage_account_type = "MyStorAccount"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = var.vm_disk_sizes.pvs[count.index]
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "vm_cca" {
  count                = 2
  name                 = "cca-disk-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  location             = "useast"
  resource_group_name  = "MyRGName"
  storage_account_type = "MyStorAccount"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = var.vm_disk_sizes.cca[count.index]
}

This produces the below error (repeated for both resources):
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on compute.tf line 8, in resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "my_vms":
│  8:   disk_size_gb         = var.vm_disk_sizes.vm[count.index]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ count.index is a number
│     │ var.vm_disk_sizes.vm is a number
│
│ This value does not have any indices.

I can't use "var.vm_disk_sizes.vm${count.index}" as this is a variable name and putting it in double quotes will just make it a string. I did try using ${var.vm_disk_sizes.vm${count.index}} but it doesn't like this either
Can this be done without making the variable a list rather than a map? I'm using a map as my actual map is larger, and it would be difficult to split this into multiple lists for all the different VMs and disk sizes.

Ideally, you would use the for_each meta-argument instead (since your variable is defined as a map):
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "my_vms" {
  for_each             = var.vm_disk_sizes
  name                 = "vm-disk-${each.key}"
  location             = "useast"
  resource_group_name  = "MyRGName"
  storage_account_type = "MyStorAccount"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = each.value
}


That would still require me to use separate variables for each set of machines. I have edited my question some to (hopefully) make it a bit more clear.

@Dragonsys While your comment is true, this answer is the same level of complexity as what you are currently attempting (tradeoff between resource and variable). Also since the answer to "Can this be done without making the variable a list rather than a map?" for this approach is "no", you would either need to use the above answer, or approach the problem quite differently. Also the list approach would be difficult to always accurately correlate to your disks.

@MatthewSchuchard that is what I figured, after Marko E's answer, but thought I would check anyway. Thank you for the explanation. I will accept the above as the answer.

I did find a way to do this, using part of Marko E's answer, for anyone else who might come along later. I had to make lists for each item, but I can keep them groups by using an object mapping
I changed my variable map to an object, and then var.vm_disk_sizes.pvs[count.index] worked as expected
variables.tf
variable "disk_share_sizes" {
  description = "Sizes for VM Disks and File Shares"
  type        = object({
    pvs  = list(number)
    cca  = list(number)
  })
  default = {
    fileshare   = 2048
    pvs        = [20,10]
    cca        = [50,80]
  }
}

compute.tf
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "vm_pvs" {
  count                = 2
  name                 = "pvs-disk-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  location             = "useast"
  resource_group_name  = "MyRGName"
  storage_account_type = "MyStorAccount"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = var.disk_share_sizes.pvs[count.index]
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "vm_cca" {
  count                = 2
  name                 = "cca-disk-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"
  location             = "useast"
  resource_group_name  = "MyRGName"
  storage_account_type = "MyStorAccount"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = var.disk_share_sizes.cca[count.index]
}

